# Adding image on listview metro app

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

```
public class ImageChannel
    {
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://" + this.ImagePath));
            }
        }

        public List<ImageChannel> ImageChannels
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<ImageChannel>() 
           {
              new ImageChannel() { ImagePath="/Assets/image.png" }};
                // the other images
            }

        }
    }

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageChannels}" Margin="222,10,340,140">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image  Height="113" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="None"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Why is this not working? I'm really lost here. I'm just trying to add an image next to the Item I add in the listview for example  "Image"|"Microsoft", etc.. Thanks!

Comment: Is ImageChannel your DataContext?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, change the declaration of your Image property from ...

```
public ImageSource Image
```

to

```
public BitmapImage Image
```

Your implementation of the ImageChannels property get accessor will create the list every time it is accessed. It would make more sense to declare and initialize a member list of List in your ImageChannel class and just return it in the get accessor.

The binding in your XAML code for Image.Source is incomplete.  You need to indicate what you are binding it to.

```
<Image Height="113" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None" />
```

If you fix up these issues you should be a lot closer to getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

First your ImageChannel class should look like this:

```
public class ImageChannel
{
   public string ImagePath { get; set; }

   public BitmapImage Image
   {
       get
       {
          return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx://" + this.ImagePath));
       }
   }
}
```

then in your code behind, create a list of ImageChannel objects as you would want to:

```
List<ImageChannel> imageChannel = new List<ImageChannel>();
imageChannel.Add(new ImageChannel()
{
  ImagePath = "image path here"
});
```

Then assign the ImageChannel List object to the ListView's itemsSource Property

```
myListView.itemsSource = imageChannel;
```

Your ListView control in the xaml should look like this

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" Margin="222,10,340,140">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <Image  Height="113" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None"/>
             </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This should work for you.